# particles are too far away from my object

Tags: particles

I have made a particle system with vine leaves to be attached to a branch. But the leaf particles are too distant from my main object. I cant figure out in the settings how to get them closers to the branch.

[image]

Comment: Heres the Blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=RnSnG2Ee" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/RnSnG2Ee/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "leaf" *Particles* are far from the emitter object because your leaf *Object* (the one you're using to instance the particles) is offset from its own origin point (see image below):

[image: Leaf]

Since your object is rather simple, it is easy to fix - just select the object and select "Geometry to Origin" - this will put the leaf at it's own origin (which also happens to be the world origin).

[image: Leaf2]

The result after the operation looks like this. You will see that the leafs are partially "inside" the emitter tree - this is because the last operation placed the geometry so the origin is right in the center:
[image: Leaf3]

To fix this, just enter edit mode, select the whole mesh and move it "up" so the origin point is at the base of the leaf stem.

[image: Leaf4]